# Finding relationship between xml nodes using js and or php

Tags: php, xml, relationship, traversal, similarity

this is more of a speculative question as to what you all consider to be the best approach or smartest method to a particular problem I have.

I am developing a web app currently which is largely driven by a huge XML tree. The point of the app is to randomly generate an appropriate sequence of nodes based on their relationship to one another.

The nodes are really well categorized but the initial selection needs to be largely stochastic and the next selections based on the first node. The choices should be random but there should not be a noticeable and logical similarity between each selection.

For example given the following tree:

```
<things>
    <foods>
        <fruits>
            <fruit>apple</fruit>
            <fruit>orange</fruit>
            <fruit>melon</fruit>
            <fruit>banana</fruit>
            <fruit>grape</fruit>
        </fruits>
        <vegetables>
            <vegetable>potato</vegetable>
            <vegetable>carrot</vegetable>
            <vegetable>onion</vegetable>
            <vegetable>leek</vegetable>
        </vegetables>
    </foods>
    <animals>
        <birds>
            <bird>penguin</bird>
            <bird>ostrich</bird>
            <bird>parrot</bird>
            <bird>crow</bird>
            <bird>emu</bird>
        </birds>
        <fish>
            <fish>cod</fish>
            <fish>plaice</fish>
            <fish>salmon</fish>
            <fish>shark</fish>
            <fish>tuna</fish>
        </fish>
    </animals>
</things>
```

... if the first item selected is shark, then tuna is a close relative, though an item from the birds category is also accessible as it holds a certain similarity - it is a living thing. However, a vegetable is entirely unrelated and should not be selected.

Considering the fact that my xml tree is absolutely huge I need an intelligent way of performing similarity checks.

Any thoughts, opinions, or guidance is greatly appreciated. I have searched for a solution on this already but so far have come up with very little.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you find the similarity at high level English language?

Comment: I suppose in my case it is not really a matter of the relationship between the words in particular, but rather about estimating links between words based on their proximity. The XML structure is incredibly dense and consists of numerous categories and subcategories, many of which are intertwined. I had thought of potentially indexing all elements, as the xml structure is not likely to change all that often, and then based on the index of the object selected, compare relevant parents.

Comment: Sounds like a `data mapping` / `attribute tagging` exercise for all entities and select `similar items` based on tag matching etc.

Comment: @Pushpesh how would you generally approach the issue in that case? I have the xml tree and it is a static file that will probably only change every year or so. The xml can be found at: http://www.image-net.org/api/xml/structure_released.xml You will see it takes a while to load as the file is massive but it is relatively clear what the categories and subcategories represent.

Comment: Quite large this file. Btw, pl see my post.

Answer (score 1):

Rather big, an 8.5 MB file!...and you plan to use this on the fly? That's why i said that data mapping/attribute tagging and storing it all in a database would be more efficient.

I see every `<synset>` has a `wnid` and word and encloses all `<synset>` tags which are a subset of it. That's how the recommendations will come. Say, `Shark` is selected...then we can search the topmost `sysnet` node which has this word in its attributes(`gloss`?), then select all the words from the `sysnet` tags within this tag....which can serve as "Similar Items"...

Comment: thanks for your response. Yes I know the file is massive :) I'd never intended on calling the file itself on the fly, don't worry about that I think I would kill my server by doing that constantly. I was just going to parse the file one time and store the outcomes in a more efficient way.

Comment: I had thought of the gloss approach before but the issue with this is that the enclosing synsets will often not make reference to the items in question but rather describe the category. I had thought of stepping through the xml and for each node, index its lineage, e.g. [synset group 1]->[child group 4]->[child group 3]->[child 4]. I had thought that this would allow me to recursively compare the parents of each selected item